# funtion returning required proper case

Tags: sql, oracle

i need a function that takes the column name having values

```
values(

feature plush

^Ido ^3d

^Imc Toys

^Tmnt - ^Lpl

^Bo-po

)
```

like this and return it like this

```
(

Feature Plush

IDO 3D

IMC Toys

TMNT - LPL

BO-PO

)
```

Please help me

Comment: How do you know that, say, IDO should be entirely capitalised, while, say, Toys`should only have its first character capitalised? Is that what the ^ indicates? We should not have to guess the rules, and you should show us how far you have got trying to write this yourself.

Comment: Yes ^ carrot sign indicates that the word should be in all caps

Comment: `carrot` <> `caret` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here this below function works for your requirement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function DOING_XX (String_In IN Varchar2) Return Varchar2 Is

i Number(2);
string_out varchar2(1000) := '';

Begin

    FOR i in 1..((LENGTH(String_In) - LENGTH(REPLACE(String_In,' ','')) ) + 1)
    LOOP

        If i != 1 
        Then 
            string_out := String_out||' ';
        End If;

        If( SubStr( REGEXP_SUBSTR(String_In,'[^ ]+',1,i) , 1 , 1) = '^' )
        Then
            string_out := String_out || UPPER(SubStr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(String_In,'[^ ]+',1,i),2));
        Else
            string_out := String_out || INITCAP(REGEXP_SUBSTR(String_In,'[^ ]+',1,i));
        End If;

    End LOOP;

    Return trim(string_out);

End;
/

with x as(
select 'feature    plush' a from dual union all
select '^Ido ^3d' a from dual union all
select '^Imc Toys' a from dual union all
select '^Tmnt - ^Lpl' a from dual union all
select '^Bo-po' a from dual
)
select DOING_XX(a) from x
```

I would like to let you know that it will return unwanted trailing spaces in case the number of spaces between two works != 1. For that you need a better regexp_substr to catch that. `Return trim(string_out)` is a temporary fix for the same.

Comment: your welcome. Next time you post a question please also add what you had tried so far so community can help you fix that instead of creating from scratch. Also if you are happy, you can mark my answer as correct.